# Can i deploye node.js application without any server in it on heroku? just cron jobs function

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

i have an node.js application which has a index.js file in that file i import two function from different file to run my jobs , now when i deployed it on heroku its starting my application and then heroku says process exited with status 0 and state chnage from up to crashed

how can i keep it runiing so my cron job executes every day

i use cron package , and just change my procfile which contian worker: node index.js but its not working as expected , should i need a server to keep it running